# Statistical methods for analysing correlation between stock price index and natural disasters

Tags: time-series, correlation

Can someone help me identify what statistical method (or any method) that I can use to correlate the effects of natural disasters on Stock Market Index?

Comment: Spelling "Merrill" different doesn't help Mr. Lynch ;). Interesting question, but I think it is far to open and will probably be closed..

Comment: You will want some sort of time series model. I've added "time series" to your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working paper which tries to determine effects of disasters on short-run and long-run economic growth:

http://www.economics.hawaii.edu/research/workingpapers/WP_10-6.pdf

It seems they are building panel model where you have some benchmark country for the country affected by disaster.